# textbox validation with jQuery, reject numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the help of stack overflow i got the below code for text box validation on conditions

1. it must contain atleast 3 characters
2. it must contain atleast one vowel
3. it must contain only alphabets
4. submit button must be enabled only if above 3 condtions are met

   ```
   var $input = $('#myinput');
   var $error = $('.error');
   var $submit = $('#submit');
   var Filters = {
       min: {
           re: /.{3,}/,
           error: 'Must be at least 3 characters.'
       },
       char: {
           re: /[a-z]/i,
           error: 'Must be only letters.'
       },
       vowel: {
           re: /[aeiou]/i,
           error: 'Must have at least one vowel.'
       }
   };

       function test(value, filters) {
           var isValid = false;
           for (var i in filters) {
               isValid = filters[i].re.test(value);
               $error.hide();
               $submit.show();
               if (!isValid) {
                   $error.show().text(filters[i].error);
                   $submit.hide();
                   break;
               }
           }
           return isValid;
       }

       $input.on('keyup blur', function() {
           test(this.value, Filters);
       });
   ```

But still, it is accepting numbers.. consider the input is aa99. its enabling button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the demo I posted in your last question `aa99` does NOT validate try it http://jsbin.com/ezatap/6/edit.

Instead of `/[a-z]/i` use `/^[a-z]+$/i`

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged your question with JavaScript

Here's a pure JavaScript solution, This may help you.

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox" onkeyup="CheckMe(this);" />
<input type="button" id="btn" disabled="disabled" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    function CheckMe(sender) {
        if (sender.value.length < 3) {
            document.getElementById('btn').disabled = true;
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < sender.value.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(sender.value[i]) || vowels.indexOf(sender.value[i]) < 0) {
                document.getElementById('btn').disabled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('btn').disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```